# Ellipse Question

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

I have only worked with ellipses aligned with the x or y axis. However, how can I approach the following:

Suppose we have an ellipse centered at the origin of the following form

$$ax^2 + b xy +c y^2 + d = 0$$

How would I go about finding the axes on which it lies. As clearly this will be a rotated ellipse.

Comment: Read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Elimination_of_the_xy_term_by_the_rotation_formula) or [this PDF](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS/upfiles/RotationofAxes.pdf). If they enable you to solve the problem, you can post your solution and (after a few hours) accept it. If not, you can ask for further help.

Comment: Are you familiar with "completing the square"? Can you see how to apply it to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  [Derivation of the rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Derivation_of_the_rotation_formula), find $\theta$ to remove $xy$ from the equation.

Here $x=x'\cos \theta-y'\sin \theta$ and $y=x'\sin\theta +y'\cos\theta$

So, $x'=x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta,y'=y\cos \theta-x\sin \theta$.

Comment: Yes I figured out how to do this problem thanks to Brian's link.

Comment: Sorry, I have observed the link just now, thanks Brian for your PDF link.

Comment: @katari, could you please un-accept the answer as I want to delete it as it's redundant.

Comment: @ Money.SE we have a push to avoid "answers in comments" and would have pushed Brian to resubmit his comment as a full answer. Removing yours would just leave this with no 'answers' which would be silly, the linked articles are great. So long as the links don't break.