# Canonical form of conic section

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

I have $x^2+2xy-2y^2+x-4y=0$ and I have to find its canonical form, but I'm a little confused.. I'd like to understand very well what I have to do.. Can you help me, please?
Thanks!

Comment: First of all, decide whether it is an ellipse, a hyperbola, or a parabola. This is easy.

Comment: May have a look  into : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194535/ellipse-question

Comment: @Siminore, yes it is easy! :) But then.. what do I have to do? I'd like to understand the steps needed to get the canonical form. Could you help me?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm sorry, thank you, but my Prof doesn't like this proceeding...

Comment: @sunrise What are you allowed to use, then?

Comment: @Siminore I can only use translations + rotations.. I can't use the derivation of rotation formula. I have to find the centre of the conic and then, using the equations set $\begin {cases}x=X+ \alpha \\ y=Y+\beta \end{cases}$ $(\alpha, \beta$ are center coords), I have to substitute these x and y in the equation of the conic. Then, I know that I have to diagonalize a matrix but.. which matrix? and then? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to eliminate the term involving $xy$. The simplest way for this example is to notice that $x^2+2xy=(x+y)^2-y^2$. So we use new variables $X=x+y, Y=y$ or $x=X-Y, y=Y$.
Making this substitution gives $X^2-3Y^2+X-5Y=0$, and so it is a hyperbola.