# Canonical form of a curve (geometry)

Tags: analytic-geometry, transformation, plane-curves, orthonormal

I am bothering with this geometric problem more than half a day and couldn't understand it yet. Here it is:

*In orthonormal coordinate system K=Oxy we have a curve*

*C:* $9x^2 - 4xy + 6y^2 + 6x - 8y + 2 = 0$

*Find the canonical equation of the curve and the successive coordinate transformations by which the given equation is converted to canonical.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

---

p.s.Sorry for my English

Comment: Related: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195690/canonical-form-of-conic-section]

Comment: thanks for the link but that doesn't help me too much...